# Unique Reports for a page Layout in VisualForce

Tags: apex, visualforce

I'm currently trying to set up reports to display on campaign page layouts to make our analytics a bit less tedious but I want them to be unique to the campaign.  I know that  will pull the report to the layout but can I have that call a different report each time instead of the ID I specify?

Comment: What do you mean "a different report?" Do you mean a report customized to the Campaign that the report is on? Use inline page layout reports or use the pv0 trick (search on Google for that) and pass in the Campaign Id.